# Batch file doesn't run robot framework command

Tags: batch-file, robotframework

I've been writing robot code in python and wanted to create a batch file so I has a simple GUI for a non code person can use it and not have to open pycharm.

So far I've the batch code as follow:

```
@echo 
Title Create a script to run my test cases 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Input
Cls
ECHO.
cd C:\Users\fivieira\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectUpdated\pythonProject
Call :InputBox "Introduza o numero: 1-Todos os testes 2-Testes de Pesquisa 3-Testes carrinho" "Introduza um valor:" VAR1
ECHO Teste numero : "!VAR1!"
IF "!VAR1!" == "1" goto TodosTestes
IF "!VAR1!" == "2" goto TestesPesquisa
IF "!VAR1!" == "3" goto TestesCarrinho
Pause
EXIT
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:InputBox <Your Message> <InputBox Title> <Reply Variable>
Powershell -Command "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('"%~1"','"%~2"')}">"%TEMP%\out.tmp"
set /p %3=<"%TEMP%\out.tmp"
Exit /B
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:TodosTestes
ECHO 1-Todos os testes
start robot -d results amazontests.robot
Pause
Exit /B 
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:TestesPesquisa
echo 2-Testes de Pesquisa
start robot -i pesquisa -d results amazontests.robot
Pause
Exit /B 
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:TestesCarrinho
ECHO 3-Testes carrinho
start robot -i cart -d results amazontests.robot
Pause
Exit /B 
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:END
```

However, only the `start robot -d results amazontests.robot` from the first IF statement works. The other 2, open a new cmd window but is immediately closed as if the command is invalid. The command is well written and can be executed on pycharm terminal and on the cmd line outside of a batch script.
I've written much more conditions but they all fail because of this.

Comment: I cannot help on that batch file code, I just want to suggest for you to try RIDE, which allows easy selection of the tests to run (if your user knows enough English). See the project page: https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE